# How to use SQL find first matching result from one table in another table?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, partition

Suppose I had two tables:

```
Customer -
ID  | Name  | Etc
1   | One   |
2   | Two   |
3   | Three |
4   | Four  |
5   | Five  |
... | ...   |

Sales - 
Customer ID | Date | Amount
5           | 1/20 | $45
5           | 3/19 | $145
3           | 8/19 | $453
7           | 3/20 | $4513
3           | 9/20 | ...
1           | 3/20 | ...
1           | 1/20 | ...
```

What I want to do is write a query that will find the first sale for each customer.  I am not sure exactly how to do it.  I feel like this is group by problem, but the answer is not coming to me.

EDIT:
I feel like my first data table did not fully explain my problem. (Honestly, I didn't even realize this facet of my problem until, I was coding the solution) Note: There is more than one customer per sale.

```
Sales - 
Sale ID | Customer ID | Date | Amount
1       | 5           | 1/20 | $45
5       | 5           | 3/19 | $145
8       | 3           | 8/19 | $453
7       | 7           | 3/20 | $4513
3       | 4           | 9/20 | ...
2       | 1           | 3/20 | ...
1       | 1           | 1/20 | ...
```

Comment: (Clearly,) This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. For code give a [mre].

Comment: I realized my problem is more complex. I have multiple customers per order, not just multiple orders per customer.  I will ask a new question.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a subquery which assigns a row number to each sale for each customer, ordering by ascending date, and then select only the first rows:

```
SELECT "Customer ID", "Date", "Amount"
FROM (
  SELECT "Customer ID", "Date", "Amount",
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "Customer ID" ORDER BY "Date") AS rn
  FROM Sales) s
WHERE rn = 1
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4eabf/3)

Answer (score 1):

Nick's solution is probably the most performant, but if you wanted to use `GROUP BY` here, you could do that:

```
SELECT
    c.ID,
    c.Name,
    s1.Date,
    s1.Amount
FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN Sales s1 ON c.ID = s1."Customer ID"
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT "Customer ID", MIN(Date) AS FirstSaleDate
    FROM Sales
    GROUP BY "Customer ID"
) s2
    ON s1."Customer ID" = s2."Customer ID" AND
       s1.Date = s2.FirstSaleDate
ORDER BY
    c.ID,
    c.Name;
```

Comment: I realized my problem is more complex. I have multiple customers per order, not just multiple orders per customer.  I will ask a new question.

Comment: Sorry, I realized Nick's answer works in more situations, including mine.  Thank you, though, your's helped me understand the problem better.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, you can use `keep`:

```
select customer_id, min(date) as first_sales_date,
       max(amount) keep (dense_rank first order by date asc) as first_amount
from sales
group by customer_id;
```

Comment: Not sure why Tim and I got upvotes but you didn't (unless of course it was you), but let me correct it...

Comment: @Nick . . . Well, thank you.  My answer was much later -- I actually think after yours was accepted.  I just offered it because it seems reasonable in Oracle and should be among the possibilities.